# Looping a Try/Except block until a file can be read

Tags: python

I have a try/except block in a function that asks the user to enter the name of a text file to open. If the file does not exist, I want the program to ask the user for the filename again either until it is located or the user hits <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Right now the try/except block just runs infinitely.

```
def getFiles(cryptSelection):
    # Function Variable Definitions
    inputFile = input("\nEnter the file to " + cryptSelection +\
                      ". Press Enter alone to abort: ")
    while True:
        if inputFile != '':
            try:
                fileText = open(inputFile, "r")
                fileText.close()
            except IOError:
                print("Error - that file does not exist. Try again.")
        elif inputFile == '':
            input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
        else:
            print("\nError - Invalid option. Please select again.")   
    return inputFile
```

Comment: Try checking the length of the trimmed input instead of `''`

Comment: Yes, `while True` loops run forever unless you break them, that's kind of the point.

Comment: you need to break out of the while loop after reading the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of the while loop, this has to be done at 2 places:

- After reading the file (when it is a correct file)
- After the `Enter` key is pressed. because we want to end.

Also you need to prompt the question inside the loop so the question is asked again at every iteration and the `inputFile` value is updated with the latest user input

One  last thing, I think your `else` clause can be removed as it is never accessed, the `if` and `elif` catch all the possibilities (ie, inputFile has a value or not).

```
def getFiles(cryptSelection):
    while True:
        inputFile = input("\nEnter the file to %s. Press Enter alone to abort:" % cryptSelection)

        if inputFile != '':
            try:
                fileText = open(inputFile, "r")
                fileText.close()
                # break out of the loop as we have a correct file 
                break
            except IOError:
                print("Error - that file does not exist. Try again.")

        else:  # This is the Enter key pressed event
            break

    return inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a `while True` but no `break` in your code you probably want to break after the `fileText.close()` like this:

```
try:
    fileText = open(inputFile, "r")
    fileText.close()
    break
except IOError:
    print("Error - that file does not exist. Try again.")
```

but really you should change this check to use os.path.isfile like this:

```
import os

def getFiles(cryptSelection):
    inputFile = input("\nEnter the file to " + cryptSelection +\
                  ". Press Enter alone to abort: ")
    while True:
        if inputFile != '':
            if os.path.isfile(inputFile):
                return inputFile
            else:
                print("Error - that file does not exist. Try again.")
        elif inputFile == '':
            input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
        else:
            print("\nError - Invalid option. Please select again.")
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful? if yes, please approve it

Answer (score -2):

That is because you don't assign a new value to `inputFile` within the `while` loop.
It will hold the same value forever...

**EDIT**

Once you will assign a new value to `inputFile` within the loop - make sure to break out when the exit condition is met ("*user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>*")